# Indexar views no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, view, índices

Tenho uma *view* em meu banco MySQL, gostaria de saber se é possível indexar os campos que estão contidos nela, pois possuo um `group by` nela que está consumindo muito, e um *index* iria resolver esse problema ou ao menos ajudar.

Existe alguma forma de fazer esse *index* em *view* no MySQL?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível fazer nada específico assim. Se a *view* não está atendendo os requisitos de performance tem três saídas:

- Não use a *view*, acesse os dados diretamente pelas tabelas, talvez descubra que o problema nem era na *view* e tenha que arrumar o problema que era mais embaixo.
- Crie índices que ajudem as buscas serem eficientes na tabela física, afinal é isso que importa de fato, índices são otimizações para acessar os dados reais, não dados lógicos, que é a função da *view*. A *view* se beneficiará se a tabela física se beneficiar.
- Crie uma tabela auxiliar com os dados que obteria da *view* (sua existência até facilita isto, é um `insert/select` bem simples) e indexe ela. Eu sei que isso não é o ideal, mas não deixa de ser uma alternativa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu uso atualmente a consulta normal, pensei em migrar para a view, para indexar esses campos, mas vejo que isso não é possível então, o meu problema para indexar os campos são que os campos do group by são de tabelas diferentes, eles são indexados já dentro de suas tabelas, porém com os joins da consulta eles não teem o desempenho esperado, precisava de um index com os 3 campos juntos, porém os 3 são de tabelas diferentes. No meu caso é para um ecommerce, onde tenho os produtos seu estoque e atributos, e a consulta para listagem, tem de exibir o produto de cor azul, separado do de cor verde...

Comment: sendo que são o mesmo produto porém de atributos diferentes, no caso cores diferentes. E o problema é que quanto mais produtos minha consulta retorna mais lenta fica devido a leitura do banco para agrupar os dados.

Comment: E não deve ser possível refazer o modelagem das tabelas físicas para evitar isto também, né?

Comment: Não pois tem de ser algo que atenda a diferentes produtos, então acaba tendo de ser algo meio genérico, mas esse index está deixando lento, algumas categorias filtradas, enquanto uma categoria que possui uns 200 produtos carrega em 0,5 seg outra com 1000 demora 3 seg, mesmo ambas estando com limit 0,15, devido a varredura no banco antes do limite

Comment: E meu problema de criar um tabela auxiliar, seria que minha consulta trás os valores dos produtos, então tem promoções que estão ativas, frete grátis...

Answer (score 1):

Para usar Índices em View basta atualizar o MySQL para versão superior o igual a 5.6.3, a partir dessa versão o MySQL usa o índice derivado da tabela física.